# Help me save battery, BBS dump included

Tags: battery, battery-life

I got fed up with my Android battery life and thought I should use it only when really required. Hence, I installed a minimum number of apps: Runtastic, Runkeeper, GPS Status & Toolbox, Metronomics Beats for tracking my runs, and WhatsApp, which I use from time to time in a day. I also have installed microG Project, UnifiedNlp Location, Nova Launcher, and Titanium Backup.

I froze all the running apps and WhatsApp using Titanium Backup and unfreezing them before use. Using Amplify, I also limited some wake-locks as suggested in other threads on XDA. I also have Naptime, Power Nap for dozing and blocking background activity on screen off. I have Greenify, but not enabled.

I marked a custom reference using BetterBatteryStats last night when going to bed and checked in the morning. The battery level lost is 1.6% in 7 hours 16 minutes. Out of this, my phone was in deep sleep for 7 hours 11 minutes. So, 5 minutes of activity consumed 11% of my battery. I am not sure what is eating my battery.

Could you guys help me figure out and block it? Ideally, since I don't use my phone a lot, I am hoping that the discharge percent is less than 1.

BBS dump: http://pastebin.com/066UsAwp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, 5 minutes of activity consumed 11% of my battery

You are mistaken in saying this, don't forget that the phone is on *all* the time , so that too consumes power. But yes, 1.6% is a little on the higher side, but not too much IMO, considering that you have so many apps/services running

Looking at this, wake locks are reasonably under control

> Deep Sleep (): 7 h 11 m 47 s  98.8%
>
> Awake (Screen Off) (): 2 m 41 s  0.6%
>
> Screen On (): 2 m 24 s  0.6%

but, you could also try to limit these using Amplify without disrupting, what is essential  to you (do you require GPS to be on?)

> *alarm* (com.fitnesskeeper.runkeeper.pro.Runkeeper): 31 m 3 s  Count:0 7.1%
>
> *alarm* (com.truecaller.phoneapp.Truedialer): 31 m 1 s  Count:0 7.1%
>
> *launch* (com.whatsapp.WhatsApp): 31 m 1 s  Count:0 7.1%
>
> *launch* (com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2.GPS Status): 31 m 1 s  Count:0 7.1%

So what you need is something that *hibernates* apps not in use like  [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify&hl=en) (not task killers), which is missing from your active list- wonder why you didn't enable it? ( Have a look at [greenify](/questions/tagged/greenify)tag in case you are not familiar with it and in particular [Android's native process management vs. Greenify](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/140427/131553)) This should certainly help you in reducing battery consumption

I would also *highly recommend* you to read this XDA thread [✭[GUIDE][07-02-2016]Extreme Battery Life Thread(Greenify+Amplify+Power Nap)✭](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/guide-extreme-battery-life-t3095884) by V7. It gives a very systematic approach starting with battery life saving tips and how to use apps like Greenify and Amplify to reduce battery consumption. The OP is highly responsive and would revert with solutions, once you post your BBS stats as explained in his thread. I have been able to achieve 0.8% per hour consumption following his thread

**Edit:** Since freezing apps by Titanium didn't help, they appear to be poorly designed- look for alternate apps. see [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/140427/androids-native-process-management-vs-greenify#comment180429_140449) in the Greenify question linked earlier

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am scared do to use amplify on runkeeper, runtastic and gpstoolbox as I use them for running with GPS on. I don't want the app to close or be non-responsive when I running. Also, before going to bed yesterday, I have frozen those apps including whatsapp using Titanium Root. I don't understand why those wakelocks/alarms are shown when they are frozen.

Comment: If freezing didn't help, It looks like they are stubborn by poor design and that is where Greenify would help. Having said that, please go through the XDA thread . You have a good set of tools installed to reduce battery consumption. I am repeating but OP is very helpful and good

Comment: I already have amplify and managed to limit most of those mentioned in that thread. Will try to post my BBS stats there too. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't post the dump there as I don't have the required privileges.

Comment: 1. use Greenify . 2. Look for alternate GPS apps that are not badly designed and will freeze when required and try them 3. 2. PM the OP of that thread with a request- he is very likely to help ( I know him-, use by name here- he will know :-)