# Does hibernation keep an app's memory locked and unusable by other apps?

Tags: insufficient-memory, ram, greenify

Is it possible that hibernating too many apps (with Greenify or the like) might lead to memory allocation problems via each hibernated app's memory getting locked until the app itself is woken up and frees that memory again? Or does the app's RAM get dumped somewhere on hibernation, making this a non-issue?

Comment: Possible, sure... Likely, no. But I think your confusing what "hibernation" is in Greenify with device hibernation like a laptop. Hibernation of an app is essentially closing an app that doesn't normally close and preventing it from restarting automatically, which in turn frees it's resources like RAM. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: If you see the [related question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/140427/131553) it becomes evident that Greenify **kills** apps which means that the memory space used by those apps is available for any other apps. When the app and it's resources are killed, how does memory allocation clash happen? It can't

Comment: @acejavelin The problem is I'm getting out-of-memory behaviors like web pages in the browser always having to reload from scratch just because I've switched to another tab and then back, or background services like ViPER4Android randomly crashing(?) and restarting. On further consideration, I rather suspect this is all from the Opera browser itself - an older version (36.0.2126) that I returned to in order to get rid of some background-running bloatware they added in 2017. (I may have gone too far back in the version history.)